# Is it possible to obtain a Mail.ReadWrite scope access token from the microsoftonline oauth2 endpoint using grant_type=password?

Tags: oauth, office365

I have an application registered with https://apps.dev.microsoft.com with Microsoft Graph Permissions including: `Mail.ReadWrite`, `Mail.ReadWrite.Shared`, and `User.Read`. Ultimately, I need to read mail and move it to other folders using a daemon task. I am using the Microsoft OAuth2 endpoint to obtain an access token using `grant_type=password`. This call is working in that I get back a token with `scope=Mail.Read`, but I need `Mail.ReadWrite`. Is it possible to obtain a `Mail.ReadWrite` token using `grant_type=password`?

My call looks like this:
`resource=<myresource>&client_id=<myclientid>&grant_type=password&username=<myusername>&password=<mypassword>&scope=openid`

I have also tried altering the scope to include `Mail.ReadWrite`, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working. After editing permissions for the application, there must have been a window of time where the settings did not yet take effect. I manually signed into my app a few more times and was eventually prompted to accept the new permissions. The next time I made the OAuth request, I got back a `Mail.ReadWrite` token.